# Button with logo & 2 lines of text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need a `<button>` with a logo on the left (which is actually from a symbol font) - and **two** lines of text on the right - like this:

[image]

However - I can't find any way to get the text to align properly. line-height doesn't seem to work - and the logo intermingles with the text.

Can't find anything specific on Google - how can I do this? (I have it working for buttons with 1 line of text only).

Comment: How about some code instead of an image.

Comment: But I don't know how to do the code - I could put some code that doesn't work though I'm not sure if that adds anything?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qo30jgjh/2/)**

this is  html part

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

    <span class="image" aria-hidden="true" ></span> 
    <span >Download</span></br>
    <span class="txt" >Factsheet</span> 
</button>
```

Css part

```
.image {
   content:url(http://a.dryicons.com/images/icon_sets/aesthetica/png/128x128/pdf.png);
    width: 23px;
     margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.txt{margin-right: -29px;

}
.img{
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}
```

I have used different image...